# How to solve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded error in android studio

Tags: android, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I am using `android studio 1.0 RC` for 64 bit linux.

When I run my application I am getting

```
"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded"
```

When I searched on how to solve this error I got solutions like add:

- -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit to studio.vmoptions or studio64.vmoptions
- -Xmx2000m to studio.vmoptions or studio64.vmoptions etc.

These did not work for me.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: I solved this issue by adding  dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    } to the android closure in build.gradle file. Found this answer in  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/r4p-sBLl7DQ

Comment: It's probably due to an IDE plugin, or something in gradle tasks maybe. I had this problem when I was using an older version of CodeGlance (now fixed)

Answer (score 61):

I solved this issue by adding

```
dexOptions { 
          incremental true 
          javaMaxHeapSize "4g" 
}
```

to the android closure in build.gradle file. 
Found this answer in

[OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/r4p-sBLl7DQ)

Answer (score 39):

Add this to your "gradle.properties" file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Also, read [**this article**](https://medium.com/@cesarmcferreira/speeding-up-gradle-builds-619c442113cb#.ivx4r9q9d). You might be able to make the building a bit faster, by adding a combination of those:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

---

EDIT: an updated answer based on my experience:

On Android Studio, choose `Help` -> `Edit custom VM options` , and then set the max memory the IDE is allowed to use. For example, if you want 5GB, use this:

```
-Xmx5g
```

Save the file, close all windows of the IDE (make sure it has no processes) and then restart the IDE.

---

EDIT: Android Studio now has RAM configuration in its settings. Go to "help"->"change memory settings".

Comment: @androiddeveloper It happened again after 3 builds.
IDE using 1.3 gb and openjdk is using 0.5gb I gave them both 4GBs max.

Comment: @stevemoretz Wow. Try to update the IDE to latest version. Maybe even try beta or canary versions... I remember it had serious memory issues in the past, but I think it got better... I also think that opening the layout designer or its preview can consume some memory.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I'm on 3.2.1 it's not old.It could be one of this stupid free github libraries my colleges added to the project trying to remove and test each one by one.I'll let you know the results maybe can help you update your answer or something.I pretty much think it's an external library my code can't create such error because it's working with limited data.And even those are controlled.

Comment: This library com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper with great documentation and amazingly awesome content was causing the error!!I can't seriously believe this.So please check your external libraries also when you get this error!Don't trust even the high quality ones.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I removed it from my gradle and I have no problem now.Do you use androidX?I used the latest version by this day with androidX and pretty much sure that was the problem.Not even a single error after getting rid of that!

Comment: @stevemoretz Odd. Which library do you use now for cropping then? I was wondering if there is a nicer library to use, as this one causes a (rare) crash for some users...

Comment: @androiddeveloper I don't know honestly.I will look for it.Maybe another version would work maybe not.It's all because androidX I suppose.It makes a lot of libraries acting wired after integration.For now I remove that functionality from my app :(

Comment: increasing XX:MaxPermSize was the trick in my project

Answer (score 5):

Find the **Memory Settings**

1. Cmd + Shift + A on Mac (Ctrl + Shift + A on Windows) or click on **Help**
2. Type "Memory Settings"

under **Preferences**/ **Settings** and increase the **IDE Heap Size** and/ or the **Daemon Heap Size** to your satisfaction
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue too - mine was for a different reason. I was working on backing up some files and accidentally dropped a big file in the resource folder. It was close to 40MB.

Once this file was removed, the error was gone.

Answer (score 4):

Add this line in your `build.gradle`

```
dexOptions
         {
               incremental false
               javaMaxHeapSize "2048M" 
               preDexLibraries = false
         }
```

Comment: What does **preDexLibraries** do?

Answer (score 3):

I also have this problem
my solution is ：
Just modify the `gradle.properties` in the root of your project :

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m
```

the `default jvmargs is 256` when you compile a lot of channel apk then will cause this problem !

Answer (score 1):

For Android projects you use gradle plugin, at root build.gradle.kts:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:${gradle_plugin_version}")
    }
}
```

Upgrade gradle_plugin_version to the latest one.

The reason for that is the latest Gradle version should be used with the latest Gradle plugin version.

For example, for Gradle 6.3 you should use gradle-plugin 4.0.1:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are  using **IntelllijIdea**, From the main menu, select **Help | Change Memory Settings**.

Set the necessary amount of memory that you want to allocate and click Save and Restart.

This action changes the value of the -Xmx option used by the JVM and restarts IntelliJ IDEA with the new setting.