# android multidex implementation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-multidex

I am having this error .

> Error:Execution failed for task ':myApp:createDebugMainDexClassList'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       java -Xmx1024M -cp \android-sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\lib\dx.jar com.android.multidex.ClassReferenceListBuilder myApp\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar myApp\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\allclasses.jar
>
> > Error Code:
> >         1
> >     Output:
> >         Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.multidex.ClassReferenceListBuilder

I am trying to use the multidex library because my application went over the 65000 method because i am using external libraries as [Link](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle) describes ,I have added the lines in mainfest and build.gradle file,any tips would be appreciated.Thanks

**EDIT**
after few launches I got this error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':myApp:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       \android-sdk\build-tools\21.1.0\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --multi-dex --main-dex-list myApp\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\maindexlist.txt --output myApp\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=myApp\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   ,,Error Code:3.
>
> > Output:
> >         UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
> >         java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I tried to increase the size of Xms1024m -Xmx1024m which is in file 'studio64.exe.vmoptions' but it still does not help ,I also tried in Settings>Compiler>VM Options Xms1024m -Xmx1024m

Comment: I found solution for second part in [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164452/how-to-solve-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error-in-and)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the multidex docs at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html you need to be running build tools 21.1.0 or higher to use multidex. By your error message it looks like you're using 19.1.0. Try upgrading.

Comment: Thanks so much,I did not see that version it works now.

Comment: ,I got another problem after awhile ,can you please check the update in question? if you need more information please let me know,Thanks.

Comment: If only the error message were obvious at all!!! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I am havin the same issue in different case eg. https://github.com/devoxx/MyDevoxxGluon/issues/326#issuecomment-1246742566
Can't find the solution!